# Custom message on TRIGGER ROLLBACK?

Tags: sql-server, rollback, raiserror

I have a trigger in SQL Server and when a condition happens, I need to `ROLLBACK` it. The problem is that I need to set a custom message.

```
-- This is inside an UPDATE TRIGGER --
if (condition)
BEGIN
  ROLLBACK 
  RAISERROR 50100 'custom message' 
END
```

But it raises 2 errors

> Msg 50100, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tU_COM_Proposta, Line 42
>   custom message
>   Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

How can I get it to raise only my custom error and at the same time I need to rollback the trigger's transaction?

Comment: Have you found solution? I have the same issue now

Answer (score 0):

Hi just   write  like this

```
RAISERROR ('custom message', 16, 1 )
```

Comment: Didn't work

It raises the error but the update is commited. Even using SET XACT_ABORT ON

Comment: Use  error handling wtith  try catch  in T-sql  u will get more control on logic

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this resolves your issue, but I used `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` after (not before) the `RAISERROR()` statement in an `INSERT` trigger, and this caused the insert to be aborted. The custom message created in the trigger began appearing in `ERROR_MESSAGE()` outside the trigger when I changed the severity level from 1 to 16 in the trigger's `RAISERROR()` statement.